# Using both strings and functions in Matlab UnitTest diagnostics?

Tags: matlab, unit-testing, anonymous-function

Please refer to the documentation for the testCase.verifyEqual method [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.unittest.qualifications.verifiable.verifyequal.html). The documentation says that only one of the diagnostic features can be used. My requirement is I need two diagnostics at the same time - strings and function handle. The following is simple example of what I'm trying to achieve,

```
classdef testArrays < matlab.unittest.TestCase
    methods (Test)
        function testArraysEquality(testCase)
            a = 1:10;
            b = 1:10;
            incrementFunc = @(x)x+1;
            failureCount;
            for i=1:length(a)
                 testCase.verifyEqual(a(i),b(i),'AbsTol',10e-3,['Test failed array element# ' num2str(i) ' failure count ' num2str(incrementFunc(failureCount))]);
            end
            disp([num2str(failureCount) ' out of ' num2str(length(a)) ' test cases failed']);
        end
    end
end
```

The problem is Anonymous function don't store values. On the other hand with the 'assignin' feature shown below, the value can be incremented and stored, but cannot be returned for use inside disp(). Is there any work around for this?

```
incrementFunc1 = @(x) assignin('caller', inputname(1), x+1);
```

Comment: Why not just create a boolean where `a == b` and you can print diagnostics about where the differences are using `find(a ~= b)`? `testCase.verifyTrue(all(a == b), 'Differences at elements: %s', sprintf('%d ', find(a ~= b)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include more than one (as well as more than one type) of diagnostic in the MATLAB Unit Test Framework by simply providing a diagnostic array to verifyEqual. You can actually do this explicitly as follows:

```
import matlab.unittest.diagnostics.StringDiagnostic;
import matlab.unittest.diagnostics.FunctionHandleDiagnostic;
testCase.verifyEqual(a,e, [StringDiagnostic('some string'), FunctionHandleDiagnostic(@() someFunction)]);
```

However, the [Diagnostic.join](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.unittest.diagnostics.diagnostic.join.html?refresh=true) method is provided to make that easier:

```
import matlab.unittest.diagnostics.Diagnostic;
testCase.verifyEqual(a,e, Diagnostic.join('some string', @() someFunction));
```

In order to do the increment call you are probably going to want to add a failed listener to the testCase in order to increment properly. Note that people/plugins can actually add listeners and execute these diagnostics in passing cases in addition to failing cases. As such your diagnostic messages should not assume that every time they are invoked it is in a failure condition. This not only applies to your incrementing code but also to just the message you are providing. I would suggest that instead of saying:

> Test failed array element# 3 failure count 2

you should say:

> Tested array element# 3 failure count 2

The framework diagnostic will let you know whether it failed or not. Anyway, takeaway, don't rely on invoking the diagnostics to determine failure count. What then? Take a look at the Events section [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.unittest.testcase-class.html). You should listen explicitly for verification failed events in order to add that information to your diagnostics.

For the first solution, I am not sure why you need to provide the failure count for every failure. It seems like that would be very verbose. If you don't need that then you can do something like this:

```
classdef testArrays < matlab.unittest.TestCase
    methods (Test)
        function testArraysEquality(testCase)
            a = 1:10;
            b = 1:10;
            failureCount = 0;
            testCase.addlistener('VerificationFailed', @incrementFailureCount);
            function incrementFailureCount(varargin)
                % This is a nested function & has the scope and can see/modify
                % the failureCount variable. This could also be done with a
                % property on the class ans a method that increments it
                failureCount = failureCount + 1;
            end
            for i=1:length(a)
                 testCase.verifyEqual(a(i),b(i),'AbsTol',10e-3,['Tested array element # ' num2str(i)]);
            end
            % I suggest using log instead of disp. If you want it to show up most of the time you can
            % log it at Terse (1) verbosity. However, if you don't want to see it you can turn it off.
            testCase.log(1, sprintf('%d out of %d test cases failed', failureCount, length(a)));
        end
    end
end
```

Is that good enough? If you really want to show the failure count in the diagnostics for each failure you can its just a bit more complicated and requires another nested function (or property access).

```
classdef testArrays < matlab.unittest.TestCase
    methods (Test)
        function testArraysEquality(testCase)
            import matlab.unittest.diagnostics.Diagnostic;

            a = 1:10;
            b = 1:10;
            failureCount = 0;
            testCase.addlistener('VerificationFailed', @incrementFailureCount);
            function incrementFailureCount(varargin) 
                failureCount = failureCount + 1;
            end
            function displayFailureCount
                fprintf(1, 'Failure Count: %d', failureCount);
            end
            for i=1:length(a)
                 testCase.verifyEqual(a(i),b(i),'AbsTol',10e-3, ...
                     Diagnostic.join(...
                         ['Tested array element #' num2str(i)], ...
                         @displayFailureCount));
            end
            testCase.log(1, sprintf('%d out of %d test cases failed', failureCount, length(a)));
        end
    end
end
```

Does that help you accomplish what you are trying to do?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer @Andy Campbell. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: One followup question. If I have two different asserts or verifyEqual statements within a loop, can I add separate listeners for the two asserts?

Comment: One thing to be careful about is the order of listeners firing. If some other listener executes before your incrementFailureCount listener, then that code will not see the most up to date failure count. Something to be aware of.

Comment: No, but you can look at the event data in the listener callback to determine which qualification you are working with and react accordingly. See the doc linked below and see the properties on the event data such as constraint and so forth. You can look at the constraint and ignore it if it is not the specific qualification you want to react to: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.unittest.qualifications.qualificationeventdata-class.html

Comment: Or, the listener callback can keep track of how many times its been called and react accordingly. This may mean adding listeners to both VerificationFailed and VerificationPassed events to keep track of where you are in the loop.

Comment: I was wondering if I can use the [Hsource object](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/handle.addlistener.html#inputarg_Hsource) to bind a listener to a particular verify equal statement. Something like, 

testCase.addlistener(Hsource1,EventName,callback);

Hsource1 = testCase.verifyEqual(actual1,expected1,...,Diagnostics1);

testCase.addlistener(Hsource2,EventName,callback);

Hsource2 = testCase.verifyEqual(actual1,expected1,...,Diagnostics2);

Comment: You do, but the Hsource argument in this case is the testCase. In other words, testCase.addlistener(event, callback) is actually executing addlistener(testCase, event, callback). The source of the event you are listening to ultimately is the testCase,  and that testCase is the same source event across both qualifications. You could do something like this if you want: testCase.verifyEqual(a,b, 'No listener attached'); listener = event.listener(testCase, event, callback); testCase.verifyEqual(c,d, 'listener attached'); delete(listener); This creates a listener then destroys it.